# Send data in Meteor HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, iron-router

Quick question: 
How can I send data to GET request using iron server side routes?

```
Router.route( "/api/test", function() {
  this.response.writeHead(200, {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  });
  this.response.statusCode = 200;
  this.response.data = {test: 'test'};
  this.response.end('end');
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the 2 examples under Sending a response section of [MeteorChef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/server-side-routes-with-iron-router/#tmc-sending-a-response) Website,

```
Router.route( "users/:name/profile", function() {
  var name   = this.params.name,
      query  = this.request.query,
      fields = {};

  fields[ query.field ] = query.field;

  var getUser = Meteor.users.findOne( { "profile.username": name }, { fields: fields } ); 

  if ( getUser ) {
      this.response.statusCode = 200;
      this.response.end( getUser.profile );
  } else {
      this.response.statusCode = 404;
      this.response.end( { status: "404", message: "User not found." } );
  }
}, { where: "server" });
```

So you can send your data using `this.response.end` like this,

```
Router.route( "/api/test", function() {
  this.response.writeHead(200, {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  });
  this.response.statusCode = 200;
  //this.response.data = {test: 'test'};
  this.response.end({ test: 'test' });
}, {where: 'server'});
```

**I have never tried server side routes myself, So I am not sure whether it works or not.**